# Nested Flexbox creates phantom whitespace (column + row + flex-basis + wrap)

Tags: css, flexbox

This is a weird problem - I'm actually not sure if it's a bug, but it behaves the same in both Chrome and Firefox so I'm at a loss.

[CodePen Example](https://codepen.io/Miragecraft/pen/RwRgeqw)

When certain conditions are fulfilled, nested Flexboxes creates phantom whitespace:

- outer flexbox with `flex-direction: column; flex-wrap: nowrap`
- inner flexbox with `flex-direction: row;` and flex-item with defined flex-basis (or width) such as `flex-basis:0`

I would like to keep all of those attribute and remove the phantom whitespace, how do I do it?

Or, maybe it's a bug after all?

Comment: What do you mean by phantom space?

Comment: @BerkKurkcuoglu I meant extra (unwanted) whitespace, if you check the link to see my CodePen you can see what it looks like.

Comment: I can't see any abnormal behavior in the codepen, that's why I asked for clarification.

Comment: @BerkKurkcuoglu I see what's happening, I put in too much placeholder text so if the text wraps (such as on a phone screen) the space disappears. I've changed the example so the problem shows up consistently.

Comment: It looks like adding flex-wrap: wrap causes your y-grid height to be calculated according to the wrapped content inside it like it has no room to flex-grow, but I'm not sure how the exact calculation works, maybe someone else can explain better, I'm upvoting the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure I totally understand what's going on, but it *appears* the issue is that the `flex-wrap` on your `grid-y` is collapsing the implicit `width: auto` on all child divs down to zero.

This, I believe, is where the phantom whitespace is being applied (which you could also get rid of by using `white-space: nowrap` on `grid-x`) - before the whole thing is blown back up to the width of `grid-y`. At any rate, just give the children of `grid-y` a width of `100%` and you're good to go:

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.grid-x,
.grid-y {
  display: flex;
}

.grid-y {
  margin-top: 1.5rem;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.grid-x {
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 100%;
}

.cell {
  flex: 1 0 0;
  border: 3px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-y">
  <div class="grid-x">
      <div class="cell">phantom space</div>
      <div class="cell"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="grid-y">
  <div> <!-- still broken -->
    <div class="grid-x">
      <div class="cell">also phantom whitespace</div>
      <div class="cell"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="grid-y">
  <div style="width: 100%">
    <div class="grid-x">
      <div class="cell">also phantom whitespace</div>
      <div class="cell"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, the solution works but it completely breaks the layout if `grid-y` ever wraps, because each flex item takes up the full width, two flex item side by side will take up 200% of the width instead of taking up half. The reason I want to keep the `flex-wrap:wrap` is to preserve the wrapping behavior, and unfortunately this solution breaks that.

Comment: Ok, can you maybe share a bit more info and a snippet in the main post with what you're trying to achieve here? I assumed `grid-x` meant that that is the entire x-axis of the 'grid', in which case you could just add extra cells to create the columns. Edit: bearing in mind your original post also doesn't appear to do what you suggest.

Comment: `grid-y` and `grid-x` simply dictate the direction the flex item is laid out, not that it can’t wrap to a new line. I think I might know what happened now, setting flex-basis to 0 for the flex item of nested `grid-x` probably caused the initial calculation of height to be based on the height of the text (wrapped) when width is 0 before flex-grow takes over, and that height is being used for height of flex item for `grid-y`, before flex-grow is resolved for `grid-x`. I will mark your answer as accepted and ponder further on this.

Comment: Just a follow up, this turns out to be a browser bug (for both Firefox and Chrome).